# Typing polymorphic values with multiple interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, interface

Is there any type-safe, compile-time checked possibilty of referring to values that implement multiple interfaces?

Given

```
interface A {
    void DoA();
}

interface B {
    void DoB();
}
```

I'm able to write code for objects implementing `A` **or** `B`, but not both. So I've to come up with ugly wrappers:

```
class ABCollection {
    private class ABWrapper : A, B {
        private readonly A a;
        private readonly B b;

        public static ABWrapper Create<T>(T x) where T : A, B {
            return new ABWrapper { a = x, b = x };
        }

        public void DoA() {
            a.DoA();
        }

        public void DoB() {
            b.DoB();
        }
    }

    private List<ABWrapper> data = new List<ABWrapper>();

    public void Add<T>(T val) where T : A, B {
        data.Add(ABWrapper.Create(val));
    }
}
```

Is there a trick to write this code more intuitively without losing type-safety (runtime-casts etc.)?

E.g.

```
private List<A and B> ...
```

**Edit**: This is not about having a list in particular - I just wanted to give a "complete" example with the issue of storing such values. My problem is just **how to type a combination of both interfaces** (like `A & B` or `A and B`).

Another *more useful* example: `List<IDrawable & IMovable>` ...

Comment: Score a point for Java generics (finally).

Comment: @mmyers: how would Java generics help here? Wildcards let you write `List<? extends A & B>`, which is nice (and C# can't match that), but that is `AND`, and he wants `OR`.

Comment: @PavelMinaev: I don't want OR - The Java example you gave is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I want to post this as an answer, but I'm not 100% sure I understand your question. Is `interface C : A, B { }` what you're looking for?

Comment: @Dario: sorry, misunderstood the question.

Comment: @neouser99: Well, you got the question right, but your solution doesn't work for types that already implemented `A` and `B`.

Comment: @dario: so A and B are already implemented, and I'm guessing you don't have access to their implementations. Sounds like it should be possible to proxy the implementations into a `IJoint`. If the implementations are sealed or not setup right, there may be no solution other than the one you have, as others have said. Someone else would have to comment on the viability of proxies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do *parametric polymorphism* like that in C#, but not *subtype polymorphism*. That is, you can create a polymorphic method like:

```
void Foo<T>(T t) where T : IFoo, IBar
{
  t.Foo();
  t.Bar();
}
```

and then you must pass an object whose type is known at compile time to implement both IFoo and IBar.

But there is no way to say

```
void Foo(IFoo-and-IBar t) 
{
  t.Foo();
  t.Bar();
}
```

and then pass in a value that is both an IFoo and an IBar.  Neat feature, but not one we support.

Comment: I don't think that was actually his question. I think he was wondering about the `List`.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Thanks. If the feature is not supported directly, is there a preferable way of coding a workaround?

Comment: @Dario: the wrapper that you wrote is about as good as it gets. You can make a generic class, but then you won't be able to expose the members on it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as Eric Lippert said, there's no `IFoo-and-IBar` type you can use as a method parameter type.

However, I was playing around with some ideas and came up with an alternate way of using your wrapper class that *may* be better.  I'll leave that up to you (or whoever else might search for this question) to decide:

**CLASSES**

```
public abstract class ABWrapper : IA, IB
{
    private readonly IA a;
    private readonly IB b;

    protected ABWrapper( IA a, IB b ) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }

    // Implement methods on IA and IB
}

public sealed class ABWrapper<T> : ABWrapper
    where T : IA, IB
{
    private ABWrapper( T a, T b ) : base( a, b ) { }

    public static implicit operator ABWrapper<T>( T t )
    {
        if ( t == null ) return null;
        return new ABWrapper<T>( t, t );
    }
}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
public class AB : IA, IB { }

void Method( ABWrapper x )
{
}

void Main()
{
    AB x = null;
    Method( (ABWrapper<AB>) x );
}
```

The icky thing about this is that you need to do a cast to `ABWrapper<T>` at every call site.  You could also create an extension method `ABWrapper ToABWrapper<T>(this T t) where T : IA, IB` to replace the cast if that would be more preferable.

It would be cool if the compiler could reason that an implicit conversion from `AB` to `ABWrapper` exists via implicit conversions to and from `ABWrapper<T>`.  There's probably a very good reason it doesn't try to do that, however.

However, what you gain is the ability to put `ABWrapper` all throughout your method parameters without needing to genercize the methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on why you'd want to do this. If you did, you could declare a base interface:

```
interface AorB {}

interface A : AorB {
    void DoA();
}

interface B : AorB {
    void DoB();
}
```

and store those in the collection. Of course you'd have to is- or as-cast when retrieving (standard extension methods could help here).

It seems to me that this is a possible violation of SRP, and the collection is doing too much. Alternately the interfaces are too finely-grained.

Comment: This won't solve it if both `A` and `B` are not interfaces defined by him, and there are classes also not defined by him (and thus unaware of the existence of `AorB` which implement them). For example, imagine that `A=IComparable`, `B=IFormattable`, and he wants to match anything that's both `IComparable` and `IFormattable` - such as `System.Int32`.